# How to debug js error caused by Plone's portal_javascripts compression

Tags: jquery, plone, plone-4.x

When a particular js file is compressed (***safe***) and merged, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).placeholder is not a function
```

See the whole file here:  https://gist.github.com/fulv/38ab213eeac3b16adec6

The error occurs in line 12:

```
    jQuery('input, textarea').placeholder();
```

By commenting out that line, I can make the error go away.

I don't see anything wrong with how `placeholder` is defined (see lines 1108 and following).  Indeed, when switching `portal_javascripts` into *development mode*, all is well.  So I'm inclined to believe that Plone's javascripts resource registry's compression is causing this.

Any clues?

Comment: If you want to find out the hard way, turn off compression one by one and see when the error goes away. (Resources are recooked when you press "save" in `portal_javascript`.)

Comment: Also: try to *not* use the safe compression but use the full compression. Safe compression is bugged: see https://dev.plone.org/ticket/14279

Answer (score 0):

I've often resorted to leaving certain files uncompressed and/or unmerged. Does everything work if you disable compression and merging for that file?

Comment: Yes, everything works if I just don't compress/merge that one file.

Comment: Sounds like you have a really good test case for fixing a bug :) Do you want to file an issue and attach your code? Unless you need your JS to be merged and compressed, that's probably all you can do at this point.

Comment: Does safe vs full compression make a difference?

Comment: I am going to get back to your questions, I promise!